# Vertical line in LaTeX

Tags: symbols

How can I get this vertical line in LaTeX:

`|`

I dont see a command for it, and if I type | it becomes horizontal.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Could you post a small example showing what happens?

Comment: Do you need this in text mode? If so, please add the information.

Answer (score 8):

With a suitable font encoding, you can simply type `|`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
|
\end{document}
```